# How do we know that a non-rechargeable battery obeys the law of conservation of energy?

Tags: energy, electricity, energy-conservation, batteries, electrochemistry

For a rechargeable battery, I can show that energy is conserved by

1. Discharging the battery.
2. Measuring the energy required to charge the battery.
3. Measuring the energy I get out from a second discharge.

For a non-rechargeable battery, how do I experimentally determine the potential energy before I discharge the battery?

I would prefer an answer that works for any battery chemistry.

Comment: In a related question, is disassembling a battery into its constituent fundamental particles, and then reassembling it in the lowest energy state different from discharging the battery?  Perhaps that is a question of semantics.

Comment: It is easy to measure the capacity of the battery using Peukert's law. Then just compare it to the one given by the manufacturer…

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peukert%27s_law

Comment: If you do the experiment that you described with a re-chargeable battery, you will come to the conclusion that energy is _not_ conserved unless you are careful to measure and account for the _heat_ that will be released in the battery during both the charging phase and the discharge phase.

Comment: This question is about measuring the potential energy of the battery before it is discharged, so the way it's discharged (rate, heat produced, etc.) is not important.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist how is this non-rechargable battery charged in the first place? You can calculate the potential from the energy input of that process (- the waste of that process)

Comment: Since you have not defined how the non rechargeable battery was produced in the first place, the question is undefined.

Comment: @my2cts I think if I knew how the battery was produced in sufficient detail, that I would know the answer to the question.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Indeed. Without knowing anything but the voltage of the battery there is no way to answer this question. Are you asking here how the battery was made?

Comment: @my2cts No, most descriptions of how to make a battery would not answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

Your options are limited because the one thing you are choosing to exclude from your list of options is actually measuring the energy.  Measuring the energy must be done by transferring the energy from one form to another.  (Or some crazy relativistic stuff that will not work on any batter with less energy than, say, a large star)

The closest I think you can get to your ideal is to take the battery apart, measure the mass of the electrodes and electrolytes, and look up on a table how much energy would be stored there.  You might try using a small portion of the material, discharging it, and extrapolating.

The easiest solution would be to buy two identical batteries, and discharge one, measuring it's stored energy.  Then you can make inferrences about how much energy is in the second.

All that being said, if you are exploring whether energy is being conserved or not, what you actually need to do is look at the process used to construct the battery, not just the final product.  If you could create a battery using less energy than it stores, then you would violate the conservation of energy.  Conservation of energy does not specify a maximum energy density, nor does it specify what form of energy is in use (your self-answer points out how much energy can be released once you consider nuclear or direct energy conversion).

With all of those practicalities, batteries are actually not the right place to explore conservation of energy.  They are far too messy, and they're actually so far from 100% efficient that it's hard to even meaningfully talk about them in terms of conservation.  I don't have any hard numbers, but I'd hazard a guess that the process of creating a battery is no better than 10% energy efficient.  There are other processes (especially those involving superconductors), where we can talk about 99.99% efficient energy transfers and decide how many nines we want.  They prove to be a much more suitable place to explore.

Comment: The idea of looking at the work required to assemble the battery has some merit, but you need to carefully consider the initial state to ensure you know its potential energy too.

Comment: "batteries are actually not the right place to explore conservation of energy."  But a conservation of energy perspective is the right way to explore batteries.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Perhaps.  Another thing to consider is that batteries release heat when in use.  So if you wish to use conservation of energy rules to determine its output, you are going to have to account for that lost heat.  And you will also have to consider that not all of the potential energy is lost by the time a battery is considered "dead."  Once the voltage across their terminals is below some level, they stop being useful for battery purposes.

Comment: At a non cosmological scale, energy is always conserved, so in theory you can always apply it.  However, in practice there can be much more useful ways of measuring things which do not have all the disadvantages that come with trying to account for all of the final states and losses involved.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's experimentally feasible, but if one could measure its change in mass  precisely enough, it will change by $1/^2$ times its change in potential energy, which will will be the energy produced during discharge.

If you discharged it through a resistor, then the total energy as heat generated by the resistor (plus any other small effects like battery heating or work done by the magnetic field generated by the current loop) will be equal to $\Delta m c^2$.

Wikipedia's [Comparison of commercial battery types; common characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_commercial_battery_types#Common_characteristics) suggests that the old zinc-carbon batteries stored about $10^5$ joules per kilogram. The energy equivalent of that energy is $10^{22}$ joules, so you'd have to measure the change in mass to a relative precision of $10^{-18}$ in order to get a confirmation of energy conservation to a level of 10% which doesn't sound feasible to me at least ;-)

Comment: This answer requires discharging the battery.  The question forbids that.  But it might point towards a valid answer.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist oh I missed that, thanks! There are no absolute measurements of potential energy, it is always a relative measurement so I naturally thought about a before/after test. I don't think there is a way to *actually measure* stored chemical energy without a before/after differencing measurement. It can be calculated based on chemistry and a table of half-reactions or electrode potentials but of course those those experimental values came from before/after comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

This will provide an upper bound:

1. Measure the mass of the battery.
2. Count all the atoms in the battery (good luck!).
3. Compute the mass of all the atoms under the assumption of the atoms are non-interacting.
4. Since E=mc^2, the difference between the actual mass and the computed mass is an upper bound on the potential energy that could be discharged from the battery.

If discharging the battery produces less energy than this upper bound, that is evidence the battery is consistent with the law of conservation of energy.